# RTDB Allow read only if certain items in data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have a RTDB in firebase in which I have a users subset. I currently have it configured to authorized users can make read requests, which I am fine with. However, I need to make a read request on a subset in my database (username in my users) allowed always, and another subset not reading but saying true or false based on  whether a given email is in the users object (allow read but only for comparisons?). I am not sure if this is possible in firebase.

I am sending REST requests to the service as: "myfirebaselink/users.json?only="username", but this does not work.

My database structure:

```
  users ...
    {uid} ...
      email
      username
```

Comment: Please edit the question to be more specific about what you're trying to accomplish.  It would be good to show actual queries that you would like to allow or reject on specific circumstances.

Comment: If you need to query, then you need read access.